# How to use NOT in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

[Documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-select) says:

> WHERE clause. This clause will map both to fulltext query and filters.
>   Comparison operators (=, !=, <, >, <=, >=), IN, AND, NOT, and BETWEEN
>   are all supported and map directly to filters

But when I try to select data using next query I have trouble:

```
mysql> select * from content where NOT sentiment = 1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected NOT, expecting IDENT (or 56 other tokens) near 'NOT sentiment = 1'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT` is an operator that is generally used in conjunction with another operator such as `IN` or when dealing with a boolean or `NULL`;

Valid examples:

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE sentiment IS NOT TRUE;
SELECT * FROM content WHERE sentiment IS NOT NULL;
SELECT * FROM content WHERE sentiment NOT IN (1, 2);
SELECT * FROM content WHERE sentiment NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

You can also use it as a logical `NOT` where it'll invert zero and non-zero values:

```
SELECT NOT (1+3); /* 0 */
SELECT NOT 0;     /* 1 */
```

You query should use the `!=` or `<>` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE sentiment != 1;
SELECT * FROM content WHERE sentiment <> 1;
```